# NextJS+Express: body is injected with a display:none CSS property

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I have a NextJS, Express, Typescript project and I copied the example server file from the NextJS documentation. I am starting the app using `npx ts-node server.ts`. Here's my `server.ts`

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import next from "next";

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.all("*", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

The returned HTML has a `body{display:none}` tag injected and I don't understand where it's coming from.. This didn't happen before implementing Express.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @juliomalves Hmh, that would be a bit hard to do since it would require like 10 files..

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to the issue you mentioned could be the presence of a `<base>` tag in the HTML document. The `<base>` tag specifies the base URL for all relative URLs in an HTML document, allowing the developer to set a default URL that will be used to resolve any relative URLs that appear in the document. If there is a `<base>` tag present in the document, it could potentially change the URLs in the browser and affect how relative URLs are resolved. It might be worth checking if there is a `<base>` tag present in the document and, if so, whether it is affecting the URLs in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the issue was because i was using [ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) to run my express app. once i switched back to `ts-node`, `display: none` was no longer present on `body`

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue!

[Next.js: Mysterious 'display: none;' Style Applied to Body Element on Specific Route After Adding TypeScript File to JavaScript Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76007418/next-js-mysterious-display-none-style-applied-to-body-element-on-specific-r)

I have no clue what's causing it. This was right after adding a Typescript file to my JS project.

Answer (score -1):

edit: Question has changed

Not sure what's happening in your code but I think you should serve html as static:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: My static files, such as images, are being already hosted by nextjs. I doubt I would want to host nextjs files as static, since I have some dynamic routes? Here's the official nextjs example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry never user NextJS. I see that that the grayed out element is not visible at the moment. Change or disable the transition, transform and visibility properties in css with dev-tools and see if it becomes visible. Also check the parent elements.

Comment: Hey @PVermeer, I was playing around with the CSS as you mentioned and it seems that my html is getting injected  with some custom nextjs style to hide the body. I updated the question..

Comment: Good, unfortunately I can't help you with that.