# Next.js: Mysterious 'display: none;' Style Applied to Body Element on Specific Route After Adding TypeScript File to JavaScript Application

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a Next.js application primarily written in JavaScript, and I recently added a TypeScript file. After doing so, I noticed that on one specific route (/chat), the following style is unexpectedly applied to the body element:

```
body {
  display: none;
}
```

I have checked my entire project, and there is no CSS rule that explicitly applies this style. Although I can manually remove the style using the browser's inspector, I have not found a permanent solution or explanation for this behavior. Any insights or debugging tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found the solution ? I am facing this issue in my project. No solution or reason found.

Comment: In addition to this global styles are no longer loading though i have global.css file is importing but style is not loading or working.